# Undefined reference errors when linking to boost using cmake

Tags: boost, linker, cmake, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile my project using cmake, but I can't get past the linker errors. I have installed boost both via apt-get install and manually in my home folder but the linker doesn't see either of them.

Here's my cmake lists file:

```
project(SignalAnalyzerRQ)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)


set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /home/natalia/software/boost_1_55_0)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /home/natalia/software/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread timer chrono REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lboost_system -lboost_timer -lboost_chrono -lrt -lboost_thread -lboost_thread -lgsl -lgslcblas")
add_definitions(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

And here is a part of the errors it's giving me:

```
CMakeFiles/SignalAnalyzerRQ.dir/Tester.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*)':
Tester.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16thread_exceptionC2EiPKc[_ZN5boost16thread_exceptionC5EiPKc]+0x14): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/SignalAnalyzerRQ.dir/Tester.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base()':
Tester.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseC2Ev[_ZN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseC5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
CMakeFiles/SignalAnalyzerRQ.dir/Tester.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
Tester.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv[_ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv]+0x15): undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
CMakeFiles/SignalAnalyzerRQ.dir/Tester.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread::~thread()':
Tester.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6threadD2Ev[_ZN5boost6threadD5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
CMakeFiles/SignalAnalyzerRQ.dir/Tester.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Tester, int, int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Tester*>, boost::_bi::value<int>, boost::_bi::value<int> > > >::~thread_data()':
Tester.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv6TesteriiEENS2_5list3INS2_5valueIPS6_EENS9_IiEESC_EEEEED2Ev[_ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv6TesteriiEENS2_5list3INS2_5valueIPS6_EENS9_IiEESC_EEEEED5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
CMakeFiles/SignalAnalyzerRQ.dir/Tester.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv6TesteriiEENS2_5list3INS2_5valueIPS6_EENS9_IiEESC_EEEEEE[_ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv6TesteriiEENS2_5list3INS2_5valueIPS6_EENS9_IiEESC_EEEEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
CMakeFiles/SignalAnalyzerRQ.dir/Integrator.cpp.o: In function `Integrator::integral(std::map<float, float, std::less<float>, std::allocator<std::pair<float const, float> > >*)':
Integrator.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `gsl_set_error_handler_off'
Integrator.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `gsl_integration_workspace_alloc'
Integrator.cpp:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `gsl_integration_qag'
Integrator.cpp:(.text+0x1b7): undefined reference to `gsl_set_error_handler'
(...)
LeastSquaresComparator.cpp:(.text+0x5c4): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
LeastSquaresComparator.cpp:(.text+0x5d0): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
LeastSquaresComparator.cpp:(.text+0x5dc): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

I haven't included path to gsl in the cmake lists so I understand why there are undefined references there, but I think boost should work, and it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /home/natalia/software/boost_1_55_0)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /home/natalia/software/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib)
```

This looks strange... [Install](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install) boost libraries and set [BOOST_ROOT](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aFindBoost) variable to installation
prefix:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "/path/to/install/directory")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system thread timer chrono)
```

Note that there is no need for `COMPONENTS` if `REQUIRED` is present.

#### 2

```
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
```

Found libraries saved to `Boost_LIBRARIES` variable. Link it using [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries):

```
target_link_libraries(Foo ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

#### 3

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lboost_system ...")
```

Do not use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to link libraries, command `target_link_libraries` designed for it (see above).

#### 4

```
add_definitions(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

This command is not designed to modify compiler flags, it is designed to add definitions.

Answer (score 0):

For linking you don't use `CXX_FLAGS` but something like
`SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(foo PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -Wl,-specialFlag)` where `foo` is a target and you have to replace the `-Wl..` stuff by your libraries.